# assertEquals(Object[], Object[]) in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

So I was going through the JUnit 4.0 testing and I test object (Stick) arrays if they are equal, which they are, but I get a failure test.

Stick class:

```
 public class Stick {
        private char stick;

        public Stick() {
            stick = 'I';
    }
```

The Game class - where I initialize the array of Stick:

```
public class Game {
private Stick[] sticks;

public Stick[] StartNewGame() {
    counter = 1;
    sticks = new Stick[22];

    for(int i = 0; i<sticks.length; i++) {
        Stick a_stick = new Stick();
        sticks[i] = a_stick;
    }
    return sticks;
}
```

The test code:

```
@Test
    public void ShouldStartAGame() {
        Stick[] sticks = new Stick[22];
        for(int i = 0; i<sticks.length; i++) {
            Stick a_stick = new Stick();
            sticks[i] = a_stick;
        }
        assertArrayEquals(sticks, game.StartNewGame());

    }
```

Comment: Tell JUnit how do you consider 2 Stick objects to be equal by overriding the default equals() method in Stick class.

Comment: @hello_harry thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is due to the lack of an equals method on Stick, so equals is comparing the memory address of the `Stick[]` elements and finding them to be different.

Override the default `equals` (and `hashcode`) methods in Stick.

Also the test violates the DRY principle, as you are repeating your implementing code in the test, if you duplicate a mistake from the implementation into the test using cut and paste no unit test in the world will find a mistake.